# IntelliJ cordova angularjs logs console

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea, ionic-framework

I created a new cordova project with angularjs with ng-cordova and ionic from a command-line.
I'm able to open this project with IntelliJ, but I must launch the app with a commandline :

```
cordova run android
```

The problem is that I don't have any logs, I don't have any log console.

How should I do to see a console log ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following plugin:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console`

& then type `console.log('123');`

You would be able to see console logs in 'android monitor'